# javascript go back and get previous page FINAL STATE

Tags: javascript, html, github-api-v3

I am building a page that retrieves some Github repositories and then displays a punchcard chart with the data returned by the API (sorry for the screenshots in advance, but I was having trouble with the in-built code styling). I start with a semi-empty html page and I build stuff as I get the info from the API calls.

1. Firstly, the user logs in to get all their repos, but I don't store information about it, I just pass their credentials in the header ([app.js](https://github.com/MartaL0b0/CS3012/blob/master/SocialGraph/public/js/app.js))

[image: fetchRepositories]

2. Then, with the response I paint a list of all the repos ([app.js](https://github.com/MartaL0b0/CS3012/blob/master/SocialGraph/public/js/app.js)).

[image: list repos]

3. When clicked in one repo, a new html is load, and has js that calls the Github API to retrieve the punchcard and paint the charts ([repo.js](https://github.com/MartaL0b0/CS3012/blob/master/SocialGraph/public/js/repo.js)).

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I need to accomplish is that, if while being in that second html I click on the **goBack** button, I go back to the previous page, but **having the repo list already painted** there. Is there any way I can do it without having to log in (do it all over) again?

The app is deployed [here](https://social-graph-lobodepm.firebaseapp.com), and all the code can be found [here](https://github.com/MartaL0b0/CS3012/tree/master/SocialGraph/public).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, edit your question to include your code as text.

Comment: I just apologised for that, I wasn't able to copy the text and edit it on stack overflow, thats why I included the links to all the files